# MemSQL CentOs 6.4 Installation issue

Tags: centos, singlestore

I have Installed and worked with MemSQL on Ubuntu 12.04 and CentOS 6. But I am doing a fresh install on CentOs 6.4 (FInal). When running ./check_system script I am getting the following error.

Warning: The number of allowed open file descriptors should be at least 64000. This OS is currently configured with the limit set to 1024. Please visit http://developers.memsql.com/docs/2.5/admin/admin_concepts.html#configuring-the-linux-file-descriptor-limit

**./check_system: line 313:  6173 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) $SCRIPT_DIR/lib/check_crc32 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
Warning: SSE4.2 is not supported. Resorting to software CRC32C. MemSQL recovery and log writing performance will be negatively impacted.**

I am familiar with the warning and I know how to fix it. its the Illegal instructions error I am trying to understand.

Any help in this regard will be useful.

Comment: After some research I was able to understand that this error is related to processor. as mentioned in the following link.

https://marylou.byu.edu/wiki/I+keep+getting+Illegal+Instruction+errors.+What+do+I+do%3F

I was able to run MemSQL succesfully. But I still see the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file descriptor warning, you can either read that link, or simply use the rpm or deb package to install - both of these will configure that limit for you.

The warning about SSE4.2 is not a fatal warning - the server will run fine, generally with single-digit percentage slowdown to insert and update queries.

Answer (score 0):

Read, **Installation Best Practices** HOWTO:

http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/best_practices/#increase-file-descriptor-limit

Also try restart svr